# rails app not connecting to redis on heroku (RedisToGo)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, redistogo

am trying to push my rails 4 app on heroku but getting this error:

```
Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED) (Redis::CannotConnectError)
```

on heroku logs, i have completed the RedisToGo setup as suggested by the [heroku devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo)
but nothing happened i think am doing something wrong with RedisToGo URL
*redis.rb*

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"] || "redis://redistogo:0deb5da103a95090a365444d016c59a6@angelfish.redistogo.com:9308/" )
$redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

*my development.rb*

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Action Mailer configuration
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] = 'redis://redistogo:0deb5da103a95090a365444d016c59a6@angelfish.redistogo.com:9308/'


  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # React configurations.
  config.react.variant = :development
  config.react.addons = true

  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.enable = true
    Bullet.alert = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you checked the URL via `heroku config`? Is that correct?

Comment: Yup the url is correct i have checked it through heroku config

Comment: Right, not exactly sure what's wrong, but you can try using `heroku console` and initialize it in exactly the same way in the console to see if it works.